# Forming an SQL query dynamically

Tags: java

I am trying to form a SQL Dynamically depeneding on the request

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String reqstr = "popcorn@Bucket";

        String values[] = reqstr.split("@");

        StringBuffer sqlquery = new StringBuffer(
                "insert into category_dev (T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 , T5 , T6 , T7 , T8 , T9 , T10) values (");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            sqlquery.append("'" + values[i] + "'");
            sqlquery.append(",");
        }

        if (sqlquery.length() > 0) {
            sqlquery.setLength(sqlquery.length() - 1);
        }

        sqlquery.append(")");

        System.out.println(sqlquery);

    }

}
```

The table has got fixed column from T1 , T2 , T3 ------ T10 .

Each @ symbol indicates a column value of a table

When i run the above program the output that is being formed is

```
insert into category_dev (T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 , T5 , T6 , T7 , T8 , T9 , T10) values ('popcorn','Bucket')
```

How can i fill the other values with NULL ?? For example

```
insert into category_dev (T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 , T5 , T6 , T7 , T8 , T9 , T10) values ('popcorn','Bucket' , NULL , NULL , NULL ,  NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL)
```

Comment: Add a second loop that iterates from values.length to 10.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to do that. Use a prepared statement, with parameters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Answer (score 1):

this is a really bad idea, read some about sql injections

instead use PreparedStatements:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                                 SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

for example, should work with any type of query or table action

to do your query do:

```
pstmt.set<whatever>// for the ones you want to actually set and
pstmt.setNull // in a loop for whichever didnt use
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just looking for something like this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i > values.length()) {
        sqlquery.append("NULL");
        sqlquery.append(",");
    }else {
        sqlquery.append("'" + values[i] + "'");
        sqlquery.append(",");
    }
}
```

Also I agree with the other answer. You should really look at prepared statements.